# Capture leaving page - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I would like to try and capture the page to which a user to leaving to.

I'm using the following in order to capture the event of a user leaving the page:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {

});
```

**How do I figure out what page the user has asked the browser to load?**

All I can think of is something like this:

```
$('a')
.click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

or

```
$('form')
.submit(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
});
```

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Deleted my answer because it pretty much stated what you already say :) As far as I can see, those two code snippets are actually the only things you can do. (Just drop the `var` to make the `url` variable global)

Comment: @Sime: thanks for the link! Very useful, should be in an answer imo :)

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons, JavaScript will have no access to what the user is typing in the URL bar.

But if you mean that they are clicking a link on your page to get to the new page, then you can do this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var nextPage = $(this).attr('href');
    // Then ajax nextPage to your server
});
```

Or if the redirect is in the JavaScript setting of window.location.href, then do this:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    var nextPage = window.location.href;
    // Then ajax nextPage to your server
});
```